# Can't find sklearn module

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import datasets
digits = datasets.load_digits()
print(digits)
```

This is the error I get when using sklearn. However, I have the module installed and updated. Is there an easy way to reinstall the module via terminal? Is there another mistake I didn't notice (ex: importing the wrong module)?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/patrickmaynard/scikitLearn/driver/driver.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Comment: Have you install `scipy`?

Comment: Thanks, it now works. I did not have scipy installed initially.

Comment: It is a bit odd that `sklearn` doesn't force `scipy` as a dependency. Perhaps there are a bunch of `sklearn` modules that don't require `scipy`, but I'd think the majority of the modules need it.

Comment: Indeed, that does seem strange.

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn have you installed and how did you install it? The newer versions of scikit-learn does force the `scipy` installation as a dependency.

Comment: I just did a pip install.

Comment: Its weird. pip install requires the dependencies to be installed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Evert

Even if the sklearn module is fully installed, it will not work unless the scipy module is also installed.